# scatterplot with no x variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set has a response variable and a 2-level factor explanatory variable. Is there a function for creating a scatter plot with no x axis variable? I'd like the variables to be randomly spread out along the x axis to make them easier to see and differentiate the 2 groups by color. I'm able to create a plot by creating an "ID" variable, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it without it? The "ID" variable is causing problems when I try to add `+ facet_grid(. ~ other.var)` to view the same plot broken out by another factor variable.

```
#Create dummy data set
response <- runif(500)
group <- c(rep('group1',250), rep('group2',250))
ID <- c(seq(from=1, to=499, by=2), seq(from=2, to=500, by=2))
data <- data.frame(ID, group, response)

#plot results
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=data, aes(x=ID, y=response, color=group))
```

[image: desired plot]

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is only when you facet by `other.var`, so maybe your example should include that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `geom_jitter`, setting the x axis to some fixed value?

```
ggplot() +
    geom_jitter(data=data, aes(x=1, y=response, color=group))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could plot x as the row number?

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=data, aes(x=1:nrow(data), y=response, color=group))
```

[image]

Or randomly order it first?

```
RandomOrder <- sample(1:nrow(data), nrow(data))
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=data, aes(x= RandomOrder, y=response, color=group))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can scatter plot a variable against row index without intermediate variable:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = seq_along(response), color = group)) +
    geom_point()
```

To shuffle row index just add a `sample` function, like this:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = sample(seq_along(response)), color = group)) +
    geom_point()
```